# subsetting data in R from another vector (exclusion)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame which has the following elements and I want to have a subset of records.

```
location <- c('london', 'london','london', 'newyork' ,'newyork', 'paris', 'delhi')
year<- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 2001, 2002, 2003,2001)

df<- data.frame(location,year)
```

and I have a vector say

```
x<- c('newyork', 'delhi')
```

I want to subset the data frame such that the final data frame contains all elements except the location that are not listed in x. I would like to create a test data frame, I have tried this

```
 test1 <- df[df$location %in% c('newyork','delhi'), ]
```

It gives me the opposite. Can some one help?

I am expecting the output like this:

```
       location year 
       london    1990
       london    1991
       london    1992
       paris     2003
```

Comment: Try this: `test1<- df[!df$location %in% c('newyork','delhi'), ]`

Comment: thanks! it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ycw pointed out in the comment, the negating the logical condition will give you the expected result

```
location <- c('london', 'london','london', 'newyork' ,'newyork', 'paris', 'delhi')
year <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 2001, 2002, 2003,2001)

df <- data.frame(location, year)

x <- c('newyork', 'delhi')

# add"!" to the subset condition
test1 <- df[ !df$location %in% c('newyork','delhi'), ] 

test1
```

Result

```
  location year
1   london 1990
2   london 1991
3   london 1992
6    paris 2003
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dplyr:

```
new_df <- df %>% 
  filter(!(location %in% c("newyork", "delhi")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only a couple elements you want to exclude from the original data frame, you could also create the subset as follows:

```
location <- c('london', 'london','london', 'newyork' ,'newyork', 
'paris', 'delhi')
year<- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 2001, 2002, 2003,2001)

df<- data.frame(location,year)

# Identify which elements you wish to remove and precede with NOT operator (!)
df2 <- df[!df$location=="newyork" & !df$location=="paris",]

df2
```

Take note this isn't very efficient if you plan to filter multiple elements.  In those cases, ycw and Damian's approach is better.

However, if you only have a single or couple elements to remove, the above arrangement is an easy, quick, logical method to achieve what you're after:

```
 location year
1   london 1990
2   london 1991
3   london 1992
7    delhi 2001
```